How to query for record where one field matches a word a user has inputted
I have a MySQL table named tasks, like this:



task_text
task_age
task_keywords




task text
(not important)
serene,peacful,relaxing



I need to build a query where a user selects three keywords as input, and I need to get the task_text where the task_keywords matches the three keywords the user has selected (for example, "serene", "peaceful", "relaxing").
This is my sql statement:
SELECT task_text FROM tasks WHERE task_age < ? AND task_keywords IN (?,?,?);

I am using prepared statements and the last three ? are the three keywords the user has provided.
However, when I run this code, it returns that there are no matching records in the table. This is incorrect, because it should return one record.
How can I fix this?

it is probably because you are storing the 3 keywords as 1 string

This is a really bad design. You should normalize it into a separate table task_keywords (task_id, keyword). Also what does "match" mean? Does it need to exactly match? What if there are more task_keywords than the user input?

Note that tables have rows and columns, not records or fields.

@Shadow what if the OP is working on an existing old system which can not change the table structure ? I think the duplicate url is doesn't answer this question even if I agree that fixing table design is the best solution.  I have voted to reopen the question

a user selects three keywords as input, and I need to get the task_text where the task_keywords matches the three keywords the user has selected , must include the three words or one is sufficient ? Note than in is translated ... or ... or .

@ErgestBasha from a orogramming point of view, tbe duplicate is the perfect answer. The OP did not write that the structure cannot be changed.

The schema design in broken. With the current design, as far as the database knows the task_keywords column in the table has ONE keyword that happens to contain a couple commas.
It's rarely a good idea to put delimited data in a column, especially if that column will be used with WHERE or ON predicates. The best solution here is fixing this broken schema by adding another table for the keywords, where each keyword has it's own row. Alternatively, if there are always exactly three keywords this could be three separate columns in the existing table.
